# how to rename all columns of pyspark dataframe using a list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a existing pyspark dataframe that has around 200 columns. I have a list of the column names (in the correct order and length).

How can I apply the list to the dataframe without using structtype?

Comment: Has the list of column names the correct order and a matching length?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the list of column names is in the right order and has a matching length you can use [`toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF.html)

Preparing an example dataframe

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(5,4)).tolist(), list('ABCD'))
df.show()
```

Output

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  6|  9|  4|  7|
|  6|  4|  7|  9|
|  2|  5|  2|  2|
|  3|  7|  4|  5|
|  8|  9|  6|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Changing the column names

```
newcolumns = ['new_A','new_B','new_C','new_D']
df.toDF(*newcolumns).show()
```

Output

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|new_A|new_B|new_C|new_D|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    6|    9|    4|    7|
|    6|    4|    7|    9|
|    2|    5|    2|    2|
|    3|    7|    4|    5|
|    8|    9|    6|    8|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have list of columns pre-exiting, it would work fine:

```
df_list = ["newName_1", "newName_2", "newName_3", "newName_4"]
renamed_df = df.toDF(*df_list)
renamed_df.show()
```

> But if you want to make it dynamic and without relying on list of
> columns, here is alternate way of doing it:

```
df.select([col(col_name).alias(col_name) for col_name in df])
```

Comment: Thanks, second part is useful to do some string manipulation on all the columns.

Comment: Second part gives runtime error: TypeError: Column is not iterable